# Transitions wont apply to the image

Tags: css, image, hover

HTML

```
  <div id="wrapper">
   <a href="myfile.htm"> <img  id="kohv"  src="Alumine valik\kohv.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="myfile.htm"><img  id="tee"  src="Alumine valik\kann.jpg" /> </a>   
    <a href="myfile.htm"><img  id="kakao"  src="Alumine valik\kakao.jpg" /> </a>   
    <a href="myfile.htm"><img  id="masinad"  src="Alumine valik\Masinad.jpg" </a>    
    <a href="myfile.htm"><img  id="hooldus"  src="Alumine valik\wrench.jpg" />  </a>    
</div>
```

CSS

```
#kohv { 
        float:left;
        width:100px;
        margin-top:350px;
        height:100px;
        position:relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
    }
    #kohv:hover{ 
         top: -10px;
         padding-bottom:15px;

    }
```

My hover effect wont add the transitions, any solutions? I tried everything withing my knowledge, I tried multiple variations of it, tried google. Id really like to know whats wrong with my code.

Comment: Try removing the `all` and `ease` from your transitions and see if that makes a difference? Also, your `img` tag for `masinad` isn't complete.

Comment: Seems to work for me http://jsfiddle.net/bJTux/. What browser are you not seeing the effect working?

Comment: Well tried that, doesnt work. Thanks for answering.

I am using Firefox